# How to change font size in blogger photo caption

Tags: html, css

I have just changed templates on my blog and I cannot change the size of the caption text under the photos.

The template that I have is Awesome Inc. Here is my blog also if this helps https://mylittleblog-tes.blogspot.co.uk/

[image]

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: I think the question could maybe be moved to something like super-user. It's a perfectly sensible and well-posed question, but not necessarily a purely coding one. The Google Blogger interface doesn't expose website code (or even controls) to adjust the caption font size, so there is no code to share.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this is one of the captions under an image:

```
<td class="tr-caption" style="text-align: center;">1η φωτογραφία για το 2017 και είπα να βάλω αυτό που ζωγράφισε <br>
η νονά μας στο πίνακα μας. Να έχουμε μια χρονιά γεμάτη υγεία, <br>
πολλά χαμόγελα και δημιουργικότητα.</td>
```

Here is the CSS for it:

```
td.tr-caption {
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

Change it to something like:

```
td.tr-caption {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
```

This is your first time here and that is ok but please before you ask a question next time, make sure to read this: [HowToAsk](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also try finding a way to solve your problem and present multiple possible solutions and ways of how you have approached it, before asking a question.